# Cannot get data-value from Radio group

Tags: jquery, html

From jQuery how can I pull back the data-value or Id within this HTML

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="OptVacant">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="OptVacantOrOccupied" data-value="1" id="1"> Vacant
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="OptVacantOrOccupied" data-value="0" id="0"> Occupied
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" name="OptVacantOrOccupied" data-value="2" id="2" checked="checked"> Show All
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the id of the selected radio button:

```
$("input[name='OptVacantOrOccupied']:checked").attr("id")
```

This will return the data associated with the selected radio:

```
$("input[name='OptVacantOrOccupied']:checked").data("value");
```

You can also attach an event handler to the `change` event of all the radios:

```
$("input[name='OptVacantOrOccupied']").change(function(){   
    console.log($("input[name='OptVacantOrOccupied']:checked").data("value"));
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/cJZ6y/

Answer (score 2):

use.. `data()` in jquery to get the data attribute value and `this.id` to get id

using click event

```
$('input[name="OptVacantOrOccupied"]').click(function(){
   alert("id = " + this.id)  //alert id
   alert($(this).data('value'));  //alert data-value
})
```

this will give you an alert , when any of the  radio is clicked

well yes as others , if you need checked radio's data-value and id..then you can use `:checked`

```
 $('input[name="OptVacantOrOccupied"]:checked').data('value'); //alert data-value
 $('input[name="OptVacantOrOccupied"]:checked').attr('id'); //alert data-value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

```
var value = $('.input-group :checked').data('value'); 
//Gets the checked radio data value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `value` instead of `data-value`

```
var selected = $("input[type='radio'][name='OptVacantOrOccupied']:checked");
    if (selected.length > 0) 
      selectedVal = selected.val();
```